# If you do a tashlumim shmoneh esrei do you say Hashem sefatai tiftach again?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, mistakes

If you do a tashlumim shmoneh esrei do you say Hashem sefatai tiftach again?

Answer (score 5):

[The Maran in O Ch 111 (2)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14170&st=&pgnum=278) says that the Sheliach Tzibbur must repeat "Hashem Sefatai etc.," aloud in his repetition of the Amidah. MB[10] says it should be said quietly. Both agree that it has to be said.

[The Israel Koschitzky Virtual Beit Midrash](http://www.vbm-torah.org/archive/02-18.htm) 
says

> "Hashem Sefatai," despite being outside the textual framework of the
>   berakhot, is not merely an introduction to prayer, **but an integral
>   part of prayer itself.** The Shemona Esrei BEGINS with "Hashem sefatai."

It seems therefore that whenever we say Shemona Esrei we should begin with "Hashem sefatai etc.," This would include tashlumim.

Comment: See the Yaaros Devash Drash 1 elul about the importance of it

Comment: +1, I guess, but I strongly suspect *someone* speaks directly about the _pasuk_ in _tashlumin_. In fact, I have a vague recollection that _Kitzur Shulchan Aruch_ does.

Comment: @msh210 I would be interested to see it.